# DataKeyNames issue with my GridView

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, datakey

I've been having this problem with my `DataKeyNames` value. The primary key of each row is the `GameID` but whenever I set the `DataKeyNames` equal to the `GameID`, it doesn't work.

I am enabling selection in my gridview because I want additional information to be placed on a formview. So when a user clicks `Select`, the formview appears with additional information on the row.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="Team, Opponent"
    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="360px" Width="641px" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Team" HeaderText="Team" SortExpression="Team" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Opponent" HeaderText="Opponent" 
        SortExpression="Opponent" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
</Columns>

<FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
<SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
<SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Team], [Opponent], [Date] FROM [game] WHERE ([Team] = @Team)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" DefaultValue="Arsenal" Name="Team" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: The SQL Data Source doesn't have GameID in the query... where does this value come from?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean change of
`DataKeyNames="Team, Opponent"` to `DataKeyNames="GameID"` ? If so, you also have to add the GameID into your select query from SqlDatasource. Your pasted code appears only take `Team` and ``Opponent.

Change 
`SelectCommand="SELECT [Team], [Opponent], [Date] FROM [game] WHERE ([Team] = @Team)">` 

to 
`SelectCommand="SELECT [GameID], [Team], [Opponent], [Date] FROM [game] WHERE ([Team] = @Team)">`

Assumes that the name of the field in the table, are GameID.